# this keyword in initilizer for ambiguity resolution

Tags: c++, initialization, this

I came across the way to initialize member data with parameter having the same name as:

```
class T {
    int x;
public:
    T(int x) : x(x) {}   // assign parameter x to T::x
};
```

It worked fine. But when I'd tried to explicitly initialize using *this* keyword, 
error occurred.

```
    T(int x) : this->x (x) {}   // error
```

---

Could anybody explain the cause of the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the syntax of [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), what is expected here is an identifier, while `this->x` is not.

> class-or-identifier ( expression-list(optional) )
>   class-or-identifier   -   any identifier, class name, or decltype expression that names a non-static data member, a direct or virtual base, or (for delegating constructors) the class itself

As the possible identifiers showed above, `x(x)` is fine and no ambiguity, there's no need to use `this->` at all.

Comment: Can `this->x` be considered as the _identifier_ of `T::x`?

Comment: @NERDYLIZARD No, it's not permitted by the syntax.

Comment: Do you mean that `this->something` is not considered as identifier at all?

Answer (score 1):

The member to be initialized is already disambiguated by it being placed in the initializer list. Trying to use `this` to refer to the member is an error. The value with which to construct the member is likewise not ambiguous, because you cannot construct a member from itself. That's why you are allowed to use the same name for members and constructor parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use initialization lists that way. If you want equivalent behavior, you'll have to put the assignment in the definition.

```
class T {
    int x;
public:
    T(int x) {
        this->x = x;
    }
};
```